# Java Boolean and JButtons

Tags: java, swing, boolean, jbutton, actionlistener

I have written this code and for some reason the code does not work as expected. It seems like it should work, but it kinda makes me think that the values for the "isBasic" boolean is not really being changed and is always resulting to false. Can anybody tell me whats wrong?

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("basic")){
        isBasic = true;
    }

    if (isBasic && e.getActionCommand().equals("basic")){
        isBasic = false;
    }

    if (isBasic){
        System.out.println("It works!!");
    }
}
```

and here is the code for the JButton:

```
    JButton basicTower = new JButton("Basic Tower");
    JButton test = new JButton("Test");
    public boolean isBasic = false;

    public TurretPanel(JPanel panel,BorderLayout layout){

    setLayout(layout);
    panel.add(basicTower,BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(panel);


    basicTower.setActionCommand("basic");
    basicTower.addActionListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to find out which button to activate the event?

Comment: Try if else not if only...!!

Comment: Well @A-SM I figured that part out, I am just trying to switch its value on and off when the button is pressed. For example, if the value is true keep that value until it is pressed again and then change it to false.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use else if and not just if. Try this:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("basic")){
        isBasic = true;
    }

    else if (isBasic && e.getActionCommand().equals("basic")){
        isBasic = false;
    }

    if (isBasic){
        System.out.println("It works!!");
    }
}
```

instead of

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("basic")){
        isBasic = true;
    }

    if (isBasic && e.getActionCommand().equals("basic")){
        isBasic = false;
    }

    if (isBasic){
        System.out.println("It works!!");
    }
}
```

Better way of writing your method will be:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("basic")){
        isBasic = !isBasic;
    }

    if (isBasic){
        System.out.println("It works!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Was just going to post this exact same thing ;)

Comment: The second statement (`else if`) will never be executed if `e.getActionCommand().equals("basic")` is `true`

Comment: This somewhat works. I added a line to test if it could ever be false, and it only says that the button is true. For some reason it doesn't want to switch it to false

Comment: @user2449865 You need to check `isBasic && e.getActionCommand().equals("basic")` first, before checking for `e.getActionCommand().equals("basic")`, the `if-else` statement is in the wrong order

Comment: @user2449865 Check teh new version for your method added in resolution.

Comment: Oddly, looking at all the examples, you could do something like `isBasic = !isBasic`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I like the suggestion, let me edit the resolution. Thanks!

Comment: @JunedAhsan Dam, I'm going to have to up-vote you to...what a shame ;)

Answer (score 3):

These two if statements negate each other:

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("basic")){
    isBasic = true;
}

if (isBasic && e.getActionCommand().equals("basic")){
    isBasic = false;
}
```

Both get executed when the command equals "basic", the first one sets it to true, and the second one reverts it to false.  Use an if/else:

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("basic"))
{
    isBasic = !isBasic;
}
```

Comment: Man, you're fast.  I think my fix does what it's supposed to now. :)

Comment: Oddly, looking at all the examples, you could do something like `isBasic = !isBasic`, which might be more readable...

Answer (score 2):

I think you're having issues because you should be using `if-else` statements...

Think about this...let's assume that `e.getActionCommand()` is set to `"basic"`

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("basic")){
    isBasic = true;
}

// isBasic is not true...

// This will now equate to true as well...
if (isBasic && e.getActionCommand().equals("basic")){
    isBasic = false;
}

// Meaning isBasic will ALWAYS be false (so long as e.getActionCommand()
// is "basic"
if (isBasic){
    System.out.println("It works!!");
}
```

Try using something more like...

```
if (isBasic && e.getActionCommand().equals("basic")){
    isBasic = false;
} else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("basic")){
    isBasic = true;
}
```

Instead.

You may need to change the order to meet your requirements, but to me, this makes more sense...

It might be eaiser to use a [`JToggleButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToggleButton.html)

**Updated**

It might actually be simpler to just do...

```
if (isBasic && e.getActionCommand().equals("basic")){
    isBasic = !isBasic;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer!! That worked very well, and you had a pretty good explanation!